# Add a column in output result using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need add a column in a output of command.

The command run on a terminal service and get the status of users

```
$users = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {query user}

$users | Out-File c:\users.txt
```

The output of "query user" is:

```
USERNAME    SESSIONNAME  ID     STATE    IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME  
user1        rdp-tcp#1   272    Active         3     18/11/2016 04:09  
user2        rdp-tcp#24  277    Active       1:59    18/11/2016 06:05
```

But I need include a column with the datetime when command is run, see:

```
USERNAME    SESSIONNAME  ID     STATE    IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME        EXEC TIME
user1        rdp-tcp#1   272    Active         3     18/11/2016 04:09  11:00 
user2        rdp-tcp#24  277    Active       1:59    18/11/2016 06:05  11:00
```

I have tried to use

```
$users | Add-Member NoteProperty IName($fiel.Hour)
```

in command, but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I make a change on the script and works (I had help from a person)

```
$scriptblock = 
(query user)  | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Select-Object *,@{n='Exec Time';exp={Get-Date}} 

$users = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$scriptblock}
$users | Out-File c:\users.txt
```

Because I need the file continue with the original layout, and I want to write the results bellow the previous result in txt file.

Answer (score 0):

to include new results on the same file, only need insert the parameter "-Append"
Change the last line "$users | Out-File c:\users.txt -Append"